# passing Handlebars Helper function parameters from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

in my `app.js` I require the Express-Handlebars module and activate my `viewHelper` module

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const handlebars = require('./server/viewHelper')(exphbs);
```

This view helper registers all the helper functions

```
module.exports = function(exphbs){

  return exphbs.create({
      defaultLayout: 'index',
      extname: 'hbs',
      helpers: {
         test: require('./viewHelpers/test')(num),
         foo: require('./viewHelpers/foo'),
         bar: require('./viewHelpers/bar')
      }
  });

};
```

and my test function executes this code

```
module.exports = function (num) {
    return num;
}
```

So when writing

```
{{test 3}}
```

in my handlebars file, how can I pass this number to the server? Because the variable `num` is obviously undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass a variable `num` to your helper, by doing so the test function (inside test helper) will be called with `undefined` parameter, and will return `undefined`, then you will get `undefined` as value of `test` property, it's not correct because `test` property should be a function:

```
helpers: {
    test: require('./viewHelpers/test')
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
helpers: {
    test: function (num) {
        return num;
    }
}
```

And `{{test 3}}` is equivalent to `test(3);`